# How to Integrate Payumoney in AngularJS Application?

Tags: angularjs, payumoney

I have sent all the mandatory parameters. After clicking submit button, response page is like this. Checksum Failed and Unable to process request.

[image]

html form

```
<form action="https://secure.payu.in/_payment" method="post">
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.txnid"  name="txnid">
 <p>{{checkout.txnid="123456"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.key"  name="key">
 <p>{{checkout.key="WHlKGc"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.amount"  name="amount">
 <p>{{checkout.amount=checkout.grandtotal}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.productinfo"  name="productinfo">
 <p>{{checkout.productinfo="pending"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.firstname" name="firstname">
 <p>{{checkout.firstname=userinfo.name}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.email"  name="email">
 <p>{{checkout.email=userinfo.email}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.phone"  name="phone">
 <p>{{checkout.phone="8125434557"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.hash" name="hash">
 <p>{{checkout.hash=encrypttext}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.surl"  name="surl">
 <p>{{checkout.surl="www.google.com"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.furl"  name="furl">
 <p>{{checkout.furl="www.appqube.in"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="checkout.service_provider" name="service_provider">
 <p>{{checkout.service_provider="payu_paisa"}}</p>
<button class="button style-10" href="" ng-click="ProceedToCheckout(checkout)" type="submit" value="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Controller: Generation of hash Key With Sha512.

```
var string = data.key + '|' + data.txnid + '|' + data.amount + '|' + data.productinfo + '|' + data.firstname + '|' + data.email + '|||||||||||' + data.salt;
$scope.encrypttext = $crypthmac.encrypt(string,"");
```

I am Using angular-hmac-512 for encryption:

```
txnid:123456
key:WHlKGc
amount:120
productinfo:pending
firstname:vasu
email:narala.vasu@gmail.com
phone:8125434557
hash:06d5393243d78d0e0518bb5dac11d762be576c23c3e51344f604547550328f6e0c84b9d8fed4543766e4057abb1ae87ccf1d9cb7b069cef498d2fcdcdd5e84dc
surl:www.google.com
furl:www.appqube.in
service_provider:payu_paisa.
```

I am new to angular. Please help me how to do the `Form action` redirect to https://secure.payu.in/_payment.

Comment: did you manage to resolved this issue?

Comment: is providing the salt on client side secure ?

Answer (score 0):

You are directly redirecting to the production. Instead that you should use the test link provided by PayU. [Here](https://www.payumoney.com/pdf/PayUMoney-Technical-Integration-Document.pdf) is the link to download the guide to integrate PayU.

The test URL is https://test.payu.in/_payment